# SoundCloud: Hottest tracks - API vs web page

Tags: soundcloud

I have noticed that the hottest tracks returned by the SoundCloud API differ 
notably from the hottest tracks that are displayed on SoundCloud's web 
page. Moreover, the hottest tracks returned by the API change rather 
slowly, with many tracks staying on that list for a very long time. 
Is there an intentional reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

The two pages use slightly different methods and caching strategies to collect the list of hot tracks. So unfortunately at the moment we can't make any guarantees that the 2 lists are matching up. sorry